# Applications can't connect the X server to launch

Tags: ubuntu-core

I can install and run CLI snap applications without issues, but when trying to run graphical apps it seems they can't connect to the X server, what am I doing wrong?

```
keepassx: cannot connect to X server :0
```

And for telegram:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

I am using `snapd` version 2.0.3 and `snap interfaces` gives me this:

```
Slot  Plug
-     keepassx-elopio:opengl
-     keepassx-elopio:unity7
-     links:network
-     links:network-bind
-     nmap:network
-     nmap:network-bind
-     notes:opengl
-     notes:unity7
-     notes-dpm:home
-     notes-dpm:opengl
-     notes-dpm:unity7
-     telegram-sergiusens:network
-     telegram-sergiusens:network-bind
-     telegram-sergiusens:unity7
-     tmux:network
-     tmux:network-bind
-     ubuntu-calculator-app:opengl
-     ubuntu-calculator-app:unity7
-     ubuntu-clock-app:opengl
-     ubuntu-clock-app:unity7
-     youtube-dl:home
-     youtube-dl:network
-     youtube-dl:network-bind
```

Comment: What version of snapd you have installed? It works for me out of the box using snapd 2.0.3. Can you also copy the output of "snap interfaces", please?

Comment: is a fresh ubuntu install or you have tinkered with your system? are you using binary drivers or the opensource ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the "Slot" column of `snap interfaces` is empty is telling: it means you have no snaps *providing* those interfaces, and you have several wanting to consume them. I'm guessing `snap list` doesn't include the ubuntu-core snap, correct? The fix may be as simple as `snap install ubuntu-core`. How you got there, I have no idea.

If that doesn't work your snap installation may have become very messed up somehow. I've found [this script](https://github.com/zyga/devtools/blob/master/reset-state) helps to get back to a working point, but only by cleaning it completely.